# How can I parse "2016-07-18 14:49:11,157" in d3?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am currently using d3.v4, where

```
"2016-07-18 14:49:11"
```

is parsed by simply:

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
```

how can I parse `"2016-07-18 14:49:11,157"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need `%L` for milliseconds:

> %L - milliseconds as a decimal number [000, 999].

So, your `parseDate` has to be:

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%L")
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = "2016-07-18 14:49:11,157";
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%L")
console.log(parseDate(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```